# Unable to use $ionicSideMenuDelegate with $inject

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection

I am refactoring my whole app, and Im now following John Papa's styleguide. 
**Basically my controller went from :**

```
.controller('TutorialCtrl', function($scope, $state, $ionicSlideBoxDelegate, $ionicSideMenuDelegate) {

  $ionicSideMenuDelegate.canDragContent(false);

}
```

(using anonymous function) 
**to**

```
(function(){
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('app.tutorial')
    .controller('TutorialCtrl', TutorialCtrl);

    TutorialCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', '$state', '$ionicSlideBoxDelegate', '$ionicSideMenuDelegate'];

    function TutorialCtrl() {
      //do stuff here
    }
```

And I cannot see how to get it to work. I was using the anonymous declaration function to use $ionicSideMenuDelegate, and now I guess I have to declare a function to make that happens. Im not sure if thats the way to go, because when I tried :

```
angular.controller('TutorialCtrl', TutorialCtrl);

TutorialCtrl.$inject = ['$state', '$ionicSlideBoxDelegate', '$ionicSideMenuDelegate'];

function TutorialCtrl($ionicSideMenuDelegate) {
      $ionicSideMenuDelegate.canDragContent(false);
}
```

It says "$ionicSideMenuDelegate.canDragContent is not a function", and when I try :

```
angular.controller('TutorialCtrl', TutorialCtrl);

    TutorialCtrl.$inject = [
        '$scope',
        '$state', 
        '$ionicSlideBoxDelegate', 
        '$ionicSideMenuDelegate'
    ];
    $scope.$on('$ionicView.enter', function () {
        $ionicSideMenuDelegate.canDragContent(false);
    });
```

It says $scope is not defined. Im kinda lost and struggling on this... any help is appreciated ! Shouldnt be too hard but I can't figure out. I hope this is clear enough !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `$inject` to inject your dependencies, you need to pass the same dependencies in same order as function parameters as well! So, the following should work!

```
angular.controller('TutorialCtrl', TutorialCtrl);

TutorialCtrl.$inject = ['$state', '$ionicSlideBoxDelegate', '$ionicSideMenuDelegate'];

function TutorialCtrl($state, $ionicSlideBoxDelegate, $ionicSideMenuDelegate) {
      $ionicSideMenuDelegate.canDragContent(false);
}
```

Comment: Oooh okay I totally forgot about that ! Thanks it works now ! :)

Comment: @DevMoutarde no issues. this kind of mistakes happen all the time :) glad that helped. please upvote and accept once timer goes off

Comment: Sure, will do when Im allowed to ! :D